# How do I create a draggable div with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using a modified version of the w3 schools example to have multiple draggable boxes containing information and it works very well, but now I must turn that into a function that can be called at any time. I pieced together this from multiple examples:

```
function createList() {
let div = document.createElement('div');

//div.classList.add('draggable', 'list');
div.innerHTML = `
<!-- list ui template -->
    <div class="draggable list" id="list-template">
            <!-- listheader div will contain file name variable, etc. -->
            <div class="listheader">New Shopping List</div>
            <h3>List - Incomplete</h3>
            <p>Test Item<p>

            <p>Number of items : 1</p>
    </div>`

document.body.appendChild(div);
document.getElementById('listsdiv').appendChild(div);
```

}

I import it at the end of my index.html. The javascript from w3 that handles moving the boxes uses the class "draggable". This does not work. That might be obvious to some people, and I really hope this is the case because I can't find a solution online. I used to use id instead of class and other mistakes, but I've gone over it all and I'm stuck. Why does it only work when it's hard coded into the html? I apologize if this is not enough information, thank you for your help!

Comment: have you seen this one? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp

Comment: @AmirhosseinSefati that is the one I am referring to. I modified it to work with mutliple targets that have the class "draggable".